# Can the IBM Connections rich text editor be extended with OpenSocial gadgets?

Tags: opensocial, ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

Similar to the same way that the "Share" button can be extended with OpenSocial, can you add buttons to the rich text editor that would call gadgets?

I'm thinking that when you click on a button in the editor a dialog box appears which could be a gadget container - similar to the Share dialog.

Is this possible? Is there any documentation?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible.  Can you provide more details on your use case?

Comment: Use case is similar to [SnappsLinks](http://www.lbenitez.com/2013/05/snapps-announces-snapplinks-for-ibm.html) but with the ability to search the external system and select the content linked before inserting the link.  I'll drop you a line.

Answer (score 0):

Is what you want similar to what Snapps is doing with SnappLinks?

http://www.snapps.com/snaweb.nsf

If so, seems possible.  ;-)

Comment: I was hoping to reuse gadgets created for the activity stream when you click on links in the text of say a blogpost or wiki page.  I'd have to build a UI that adds the embedded experience link - if the RTE was enabled for OpenSocial, this could be similar to the way the Share dialog extension points work., but result in an embedded experience in the page content on link click.

Comment: http://ibmrockstar.com/2013/05/tutorial-extending-the-ibm-connections-rich-text-editor/ <--- an article that may help